# Material toggle button problem on Android API 21

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android

I use material toggle button group like this

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:singleSelection="true">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_topso"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

  android:layout_width="wrap_content"          android:text="@string/topo" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_averages"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/average" />

    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

But when run the application, crash with this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to get ShapeAppearanceModel from a MaterialButton which has an overwritten background.
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.getShapeAppearanceModel(MaterialButton.java:1169)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup.addView(MaterialButtonToggleGroup.java:244)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3709)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
```

I can't fix it!, how can I solve this issue?

Material version: '1.3.0-alpha03'

Style:

```
    <style name="MaterialAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="floatingActionButtonStyle">@style/FloatingButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: If you have android:background as main theme is also cause to this crash.

Comment: This, strangely, was also crashing my TimePicker. I removed "android:background" from my theme and it went again... but now my loading screen isn't the correct color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
   android:background="@drawable/about"
```

Using the `android:background` in `MaterialButton` you are overriding the default background. It means the `MaterialButton` doesn't use its own `MaterialShapeDrawable` for the background (and the `ShapeAppearanceModel`).
It seems a bug but you can solve it removing the `android:background` in your `MaterialButton`.